# Sticky footers with nested content area

Tags: html, css

I have an implementation of a sticky footer.  I actually have the "sticky" stuff working.  But now I want to add a interior "content-box" div which will span the entire screen.

Please refer to [this page](http://embeddedanalytics.com/eashort2.html).

What is needed to have the white area be the same height as the cyan area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible in this setup,

but what you can do is apply a 1px height background image with `background-repeat:repeat-y;` on the body or parent container, to simulate the white background of the `.content-box` div(including the left and right borders).

add

```
background:url(simulatewhitecontainer.png) repeat-y center top;
```

to  `div.main`

and remove

```
border-right: 1px solid #B0B0B0;
border-left: 1px solid #B0B0B0;
```

from `div.content-box`

Update: Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gqSau/ for an example

Comment: Yes!!! - Now just tinkering so even if a screen is wider than 1800 pixels it will still span across the entire screen (1800 being the width of the background image).

Comment: Ok - I just took away the repeat-y and that works.  I presume I should instead use a 1x1 pixel then?

Comment: Well, you can also expand the image to a larger width, or set the `background-color` to the color of the outer background color.
So that will be something like `background:url(simulatewhitecontainer.png) repeat-y center top #ff0000;` if for instance red is your background color. And you're welcome! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

using the following css for the content

```
.content {
padding: 0px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 50px;
top: 70px;
right: 0px;
left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: But when I do that, the red footer doesn't "sink" to the bottom.  It says right where it is, and the content of the box goes right through it.

Comment: because of the `padding: 10px;` property of the footer, just remove it

Comment: still did not work.  That just adjusted the height of the footer by 10px

Comment: He needs the white to occupy the whole screen even inspite of having content or not? But cyan is already doing this, so why you want it for white??

Comment: Then you can change the color from cyan to white, that will get what you want + the looks - @MSchenkel

Comment: But I don't want a single background color.  What I want is the sides to have a background color while the middle (content area) to be white.    Look at this page:  https://www.embeddedanalytics.com/logon.html  I think it would look better having the white take up all space down to footer.